# Content centered in local host but changes in gh-pages

Tags: html, css, reactjs, github-pages

I have a very simple container that has two svg's in them for buttons. In local host these are centered perfectly and responsive as expected. When I host my project on gh-pages my content with the two svg's in them shift the to the left for some reason. Any ideas?

Code for buttons:

```
  return (
    <Container className="button_container">
      <svg
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        width="32"
        height="32"
        fill="currentColor"
        className="bi bi-arrow-left-square-fill previousBtn"
        viewBox="0 0 16 16"
        onClick={previousPage}
      >
        <path d="M16 14a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V2a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h12a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v12zm-4.5-6.5H5.707l2.147-2.146a.5.5 0 1 0-.708-.708l-3 3a.5.5 0 0 0 0 .708l3 3a.5.5 0 0 0 .708-.708L5.707 8.5H11.5a.5.5 0 0 0 0-1z" />
      </svg>

      <svg
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        width="32"
        height="32"
        fill="currentColor"
        className="bi bi-arrow-right-square-fill nextBtn"
        viewBox="0 0 16 16"
        onClick={nextPage}
      >
        <path d="M0 14a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h12a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V2a2 2 0 0 0-2-2H2a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v12zm4.5-6.5h5.793L8.146 5.354a.5.5 0 1 1 .708-.708l3 3a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-3 3a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L10.293 8.5H4.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1z" />
      </svg>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

css

```
  .button_container {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-around;
      margin: 3em;
    }
 
    .previousBtn,
    .nextBtn {
      color: $white;
      border-radius: 5px;
      cursor:pointer
    }
    
    .previousBtn:hover,
    .nextBtn:hover {
      opacity: 0.5;
    }
```

Comment: website link???

Comment: Which SVG you are talking about?? The "alien with UFO above"?

Comment: If you scroll down, the two arrows on the bottom.

Comment: Select a state first though to see them

Comment: I am not seeing any arrows can you also post a screenshot of the same??